# This code for tire pressure keep running off the screen

Tags: c#, xamarin

The code I have doesn't work with console.writeline

I'm not to use console.readline

```
[] tirePressure = new int [4];
    string valueTestFail = "Get you tire check as soon as possible.";
    Console.WriteLine("Let check your tires!\r\nPlease enter the pressure for the front right tire.");
    string frontRightTire = Console.ReadLine(); 
    while(!int.TryParse(frontRightTire, out tirePressure[0])){
        Console.WriteLine(valueTestFail);
        frontRightTire = Console.ReadLine();
    }       Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the pressure for the front left tire.");
    string frontLeftTire = Console.ReadLine();
    while(!int.TryParse(frontLeftTire, out tirePressure[1])){
        Console.WriteLine(valueTestFail);
        frontLeftTire = Console.ReadLine();
    }
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the pressure for your rear right tire.");
    string rearRightTire = Console.ReadLine();  
    while(!int.TryParse(rearRightTire, out tirePressure[2])){
        Console.WriteLine(valueTestFail);
        rearRightTire = Console.ReadLine();
    }
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the value of the rear left tire.");
    string rearLeftTire = Console.ReadLine();

    while(!int.TryParse(rearLeftTire, out tirePressure[3])){
        Console.WriteLine(valueTestFail);
        string rearLeftTire = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    if(tirePressure[0]==tirePressure[1] && tirePressure[2]==tirePressure[3]){
        Console.WriteLine("The tires pass spec!");
    }else{
        Console.WriteLine("Get your tires checked out.");
    }
```

The error code so long, the code just run the entire screen and I just want to console.writeline this code line

Comment: Where does "tire pressure" come into play here?  I see some code to convert a score to a grade.

Comment: So it means your are running an infinite loop. Please debug your code and check

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Does it throw an error or exception, or crash?  Does it not compile?  What **specifically** is it doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! It seems like this is not related to Xamarin , and you need to share some error logs here and which line code occurs error .This will be helpful to check where problem is .

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are trying to use a Windows .NET feature in Xamarin.  I Googled "console writeline xamarin" and got some alternatives.  Try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`, for instance.

You might look at this URL, https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18387/equivalent-of-console-writeline, to see if the information there is able to help you out.

I've been using C# for over 10 years, I read through your C# code, and I don't see anything incorrect with it...  if it's running on Windows.  You might improve its style, but that's not what you're looking for, is it.

Comment: Yes I'm using system mono for my workspace but what I'm trying to accomplish is the code be wrote in just consol.writeline by have a user input numbers to see if the tire are checked out and the only way I understand is to use console.readline